# Problem with crontab inside a docker container

Tags: docker, cron, docker-container

I tried to insert a command in my host's crontab to run a script every minute but this doesn't happen.

The script is inside my container created through docker.

The script very simply creates a folder called "test".

**My crontab string:**

```
*/1 *   * * *   root    docker exec testsite4 /home/tester.sh
```

**Update**

this is what docker events show me:
[image]

Comment: Does `docker events` show the exec? Are there any errors from crond?

Comment: @BMitch I added the docker events screen

Comment: So docker says the exec is running, what makes you say it isn't? Also please do not post pictures of text, use formatted text instead. (Pictures aren't accessible to search engines, screen readers, mobile users, etc.)